# Calling a function which is inside a function in controller

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I got the following function in my controller, I am not understanding why I can not call the function b for example from another function, so I got the following code:

```
respond: function() {
                var z;
                var that = this;
                var y = 10;

                    function a() {
                       //do something
                            }

                    function b() {
                        //do something
                            }
                    function c() {
                        //do something
                            }   

    }
```

and now I tried this:

```
respond: function() {
                var z;
                var that = this;
                var y = 10;

                    function a() {
                       //do something
                            }

                    function b() {
                        //do something
                            }
                    function c() {
                        //do something
                            }   

    },

    onButtonPress: function(){
        respond.b;
    },
```

but this call doesn't work can someone explain me why?

Comment: can you share the complete code of the example, I can't get what timer variable is and where it is defined. Anyway timer.b it is not executing the function, may be you miss the brackets ? timer.b();

Comment: sorry it should be respond.b;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a function it becomes locally scoped, i.e. private to the function it's declared in.
If you want to make it available outside that function you have to either export it by returning it or assigning it to a variable/object property that is available outside the function.

Returning:

```
respond: function() {
  function b() {
    //do something
  }

  return b; // Single function
}
```

or

```
respond: function() {
  function a() {
    //do something
  }
  function b() {
    //do something
  }
  function c() {
    //do something
  }   

  // Object containing multiple functions
  return {
    a: a,
    b: b,
    c: c
  };
}
```

Assigning:

```
respond: function() {
  function b() {
    //do something
  }

  window.b = b;
}
```

Comment: so if you wanna call the function b in the function main how would you do it by returning it could you provide an example code? my main lacking of understanding is where do I put the return statement, in the function b itself or at the end of the main function

Comment: @Nali The main function, I'll update my answer with an example

Comment: I see I might confused you with some terms just to clearify when I talked about main function I meant my respond function in my example, I edited hope you got me